# MAC cloning does'nt work in a MAC filtered WiFi network

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, network-manager, mac

I have a WiFi connection which is MAC filtered. The internet connection can be used by devices with a few selected MAC addresses. My mobile is one of them and I can use the connection through it.

Now I want to use the connection through my Laptop which has a different MAC address. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I set up the connection (SSID and Password) through Network Manager GUI. I keep the 'device MAC address' tab blank and in the 'cloned MAC address' tab I write the MAC address of my phone. After saving the network I restarted Network Manager by,

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But I can't access the Internet connection. When I try to connect to the network it prompts me to the 'enter password' tab every time.

Is there any way to use the connection through my Laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `mac address` on this way.

For wlan

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Where `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` represent mac address

Or you can add `mac address` in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

then add

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# add mac you wish to wlan0 int
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06
```